# Copying multiple cells in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to this but I am trying to copy multiple cells in an excel workbook and paste them into a separate tab of the same workbook.

[image: Example:]

Above is a sample of what my spreadsheet looks like, but my spreadsheet has over 800 lines of data.

I need the names to be copied and put into column A of Sheet2 and then the account numbers into column D of Sheet2.

I have tried this 2 different ways.

1. Using below code:

   ```
   Sheets("Sheet1").Select
   Range("A1,A3,A5,A7,A9").Select    
   Range("A10").Activate
   Selection.Copy
   Sheets("Sheet2").Select
   Range("A1").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Sheets("Sheet1").Select
   Range("A2,A4,A6,A8,A10").Select    
   Range("A10").Activate
   Selection.Copy
   Sheets("Sheet2").Select
   Range("D1").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   ```

   This gives me a `Compile Error Syntax Error`.
2. Code #2

   ```
   Range("A2").Select
   Selection.Cut
   Range("D1").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Range("A4").Select
   Selection.Cut
   Range("D3").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   ...
   ```

   This is keeping them in the same tab, instead of pasting them into a separate tab (I would just copy them over later). I repeat this for each customer. This one gives me a range error that basically says it's too large. Unfortunately, I can't recreate it because I deleted it.

Does anyone have a simpler way of doing this that won't cause an error?

Answer (score 2):

Try this is assuming your data is consistently alternating (Name,acount).

```
Sub marine()
    Dim lr As Long, i As Long
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    '/* declare the worksheets and use variables in the rest of the code */
    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1"): Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    With sh1
        lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '/* get the last row in Sheet1 */
        For i = 1 To lr '/* loop to all rows identified */
            If i Mod 2 = 1 Then '/* check if odd or even, copy in A if odd */
                .Range("A" & i).Copy _
                sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Else '/* copy in D otherwise */
                .Range("A" & i).Copy _
                sh2.Range("D" & sh2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Above copies data from *Sheet1* to *Sheet2* but leaves the 1st row blank.
Also, it always copy data on the last row of each column in *Sheet2* (A and D).
 So another approach would be:

```
Sub ject()
    Dim lr As Long, i As Long, lr2 As Long
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim rNames As Range, rAcct As Range
    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1"): Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    With sh1
        lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lr
            If i Mod 2 = 1 Then
                If rNames Is Nothing Then '/* get all the cells with names */
                    Set rNames = .Range("A" & i)
                Else
                    Set rNames = Union(rNames, .Range("A" & i))
                End If
            Else
                If rAcct Is Nothing Then '/* get all the cells with accounts */
                    Set rAcct = .Range("A" & i)
                Else
                    Set rAcct = Union(rAcct, .Range("A" & i))
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

    With sh2
        '/* get the last filled Names column in Sheet2 */
        lr2 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        rNames.Copy .Range("A" & lr2) '/* execute 1 time copy */
        rAcct.Copy .Range("D" & lr2) '/* execute 1 time copy */
    End With
End Sub
```

Above code ensures that the correct account is adjacent to the correct name.
And you might gain execution performance too since one(1) time copy is executed. HTH.

**P.S.** As much as possible, [avoid using `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 0):

Logic I implemented is to loop until last row in `Sheet1` in step of 2. Loop variable indicates always row with name, the following row is account number, so it's easy in a loop to assign these values to particular columns on the other sheet. Also, I used another variable `j`, which indicates consecutive rows in `Sheet2`.

Solution:

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim sourceWs As Worksheet, targetWs As Worksheet, i As Long, lastRow As Long, j As Long
j = 1
Set sourceWs = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set targetWs = Worksheets("Sheet2")
lastRow = sourceWs.Cells(sourceWs.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow Step 2
    targetWs.Cells(j, 1) = sourceWs.Cells(i, 1)
    targetWs.Cells(j, 4) = sourceWs.Cells(i + 1, 1)
    j = j + 1
Next

End Sub
```